# Encapsulating this List<Message> properly

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc, swing

I know that Swing [isn't true MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html#3):

> Using this modified MVC helps to more completely decouple the model
>   from the view.

Leaving aside the veracity of the above claim, the problem I run into is that I can't seem to just drop a `Page` into a `JList`, but have to first extract a `List` (data) from the `Page` object.  This just seems like a bad idea.  Does this break encapsulation?

What's a better approach to handling the `nextPage` method, invoked by clicking the <kbd>next</kbd> button?

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu.PageMetaData;
import net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu.Page;
import net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu.Usenet;

public class ArticlesPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ArticlesPanel.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JList<String> jList = new JList<>();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private DefaultListModel<String> defaultListModel;
    private JButton next = new JButton("next");
    private Page page;
    private Usenet usenetConnection = Usenet.INSTANCE;  //ensures correct connection
    private PageMetaData pageMetaData = new PageMetaData();

    public ArticlesPanel() {
        nextPage(null);
        nextPage(null);  //only because default page starts at zero
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                nextPage(e);
            }
        });

        jList.setModel(defaultListModel);
        jList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jList.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mouseReleases(evt);
            }
        });
        jList.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                keyReleases(evt);
            }
        });

        scrollPane.setViewportView(jList);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(next, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setSize(300, 100);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void keyReleases(KeyEvent evt) {
        itemSelected();
    }

    private void mouseReleases(MouseEvent evt) {
        itemSelected();
    }

    private void itemSelected() {
        LOG.info("selected\t\t" + jList.getSelectedValue());
    }

    private void nextPage(ActionEvent e) {
        page = usenetConnection.getPage(pageMetaData);  //first time, default
        pageMetaData = new PageMetaData(page.getPageMetaData(), true); //get next is true
        List<Message> messages = page.getMessages(); //breaks MVC?
        defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();  //clear or new?
        for (Message m : messages) {
            try {
                defaultListModel.addElement(m.getSubject());
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                LOG.warning("bad message\n" + m.toString() + "\n" + ex);
            }
        }
        jList.setModel(defaultListModel);
        LOG.fine(page.toString());
    }
}
```

While it's messy, that's not problem I'm facing.  Rather, it's data encapsulation, I believe.  I want `Page` to hide as much data as possible, yet that seems impossible.

`Page` class:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.gnu;

import gnu.mail.providers.nntp.GroupMetaData;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Header;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

public class Page {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Page.class.getName());
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
     private PageMetaData pageMetaData = new PageMetaData();

    public Page() throws Exception {
        GroupMetaData gmd = new GroupMetaData();
        pageMetaData = new PageMetaData(gmd);
    }

    public Page(GroupMetaData gmd) throws Exception {
        pageMetaData = new PageMetaData(gmd);
    }

    public Page(PageMetaData pmd) throws Exception {
        this.pageMetaData = pmd;
    }

    public Page(PageMetaData pmd, List<Message> messages) throws MessagingException {
        this.pageMetaData = pmd;
        this.messages = messages;
    }


    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(messages);
    }

    private String printXref() throws MessagingException {
        LOG.fine("starting xref printing...\t" + messages.size());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = null;
        String headerString = null;
        String subString = null;
        sb.append("messages to follow\n");
        for (Message message : messages) {

            LOG.fine(message.getSubject());

            int i = messages.indexOf(message);
            Enumeration headers = null;

            headers = message.getAllHeaders();

            while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
                Object o = headers.nextElement();
                Header header = (Header) o;
                if ("Xref".equals(header.getName())) {
                    headerString = header.getValue();
                    int index = headerString.indexOf(":");
                    subString = headerString.substring(index + 1);
                    int xref = Integer.parseInt(subString);
                    s = "\n" + i + "\t\t" + xref;
                    sb.append(s);
                    s = message.getSubject();
                    sb.append("\t").append(s);
                }
            }
            LOG.fine("\n\n\n**********************\n\n\n");
        }
        LOG.fine(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "\n---new page---\n" + getPageMetaData().toString() + "\n";
        try {
            s = s + printXref();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public PageMetaData getPageMetaData() {
        return pageMetaData;
    }

    public void setPageMetaData(PageMetaData pageMetaData) {
        this.pageMetaData = pageMetaData;
    }
}
```

[Full project](https://github.com/THUFIR/gnumail-providers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the busy-work code of transforming the `List<Message>` to `DefaultListModel` into another method.

From what I'm seeing I would think about the concepts you want to express in your code vis-a-vis some technical adherence to "encapsulation". If you want `Page` users to have no concept of an imbedded `Message` in a `Page` fine, but as it stands I'm not thinking message is inadequately encapsulated. Alternatively if there are some `Message` public getters that you simply do not want `Page` users to access, then that's OK rational too.

In this case then the alternative is, in the `Page` class, a public `public List<String> Page.getSubjects()` - and likewise for all `Message` properties you want public. If, as far as Page users are concerned, the message's subject *is* the message, then rename the methods: `Page.getMessages()`; but it still returns a `List<string>`.

You can take that one step further by having `Page` implement iterator methods so the calling code looks like `page.nextMessage()`, `page.hasNextMessage()`, etc. and whatever. But again, the caller has to iterate. This doesn't feel like much bang for get buck to me, although it seems to fanatically adhere to [the law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: I agree that page.nextMessage() is probably not the way to go, but it's at least an interesting idea -- thanks.